# Unable to implement simple view scrolling in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, uiview, uiscrollview

I'm having a hard time implementing a simple scroll on my detail view.

The app is straightforward with a Master and Detail views.

When the user taps an item on Master, the Detail view is pushed with larger photo, blog text and etc.

I would like the **entire** Detail view to scroll, so if the picture is tall, or the text is long, they can scroll vertically to see/read more. I do not want the user to scroll these items individually. It should feel like webpage scrolling.

Currently my Detail view loads OK but I can't make it scroll.

My **DetailViewController.h**

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

    @interface DetailViewController : UIViewController {
        IBOutlet UILabel     *postTextLabel; // wired to Text Label
        IBOutlet UILabel     *postAuthorNameLabel; // wired to Author Label
    }

    @property (strong, nonatomic) id detailItem;
    @end
```

My **DetailViewController.m**

```
#import "DetailViewController.h"

@interface DetailViewController ()
- (void)configureView;
@end

@implementation DetailViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self configureView];
}

- (void)configureView
{
    if (self.detailItem) {
        NSDictionary *post           = self.detailItem;
        NSString     *postText       = [post objectForKey:@"post_text"];
        NSString     *postAuthorName = [post objectForKey:@"post_author_name"];

        postTextLabel.text       = postText;
        postAuthorNameLabel.text = postAuthorName;
    }
}
@end
```

Structure on IB:

[image]

Any ideas on what's missing to make this work?

Comment: There's not enough info. But ... 1) is `scrollEnabled` set to `YES` in your `UIScrollView`? 2) is `contentSize` in your `UIScrollView` bigger than `frame`?

Comment: 3) Put your `.h`, `.m` and `.xib` file somewhere, so, we can look at it.

Comment: @RobertVojta the h and m files are as above - no xib file since I'm using XCode 4.5 - any other suggestions?

Comment: Then `.storyboard` if you do use story boards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do the following:

1)(optional)turn your View into a scrollview by dragging it into the view in the scruture list on the side.

2)link the scrollView into your viewcontroller .h and make an Outlet connection something like this

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scroller;
```

(make sure you add @synthesize in the .m if you add this manually)
and make sure it is connected in IB!

3)set the contentsize of the scrollview in viewDidLoad method

```
scroller.contentSize =  CGSizeMake(320,550);
```

NOTE: IBOutlet UILabel *postTextLabel; should actually probably be a UITextView so you can access ContentSize
Which would allow for the following.

```
CGRect frame = postTextLabel.frame;
frame.size = postTextLabel.contentSize;
postTextLabel.frame = frame;
scroller.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, frame.size.height+200);//200 or how ever much space is above the textView
```

and again that only works if you use a UITextView

for ipad replace 320 with 768 or 1024, or whichever depending on orientation

The best way to connect it in IB is like this holding down control and dragging to the .h file
and make sure it is set to automatic like in the picture, and pointing to> the .h of your view.
Adding it like this also automatically adds the @synthesize for you.

[image]

[image]

Make sure  UserInteractionsEnabled are checked here for our scrollview

Comment: working on your suggestions - where should I put the code for item [3] and below?

Comment: parser gives `use of undeclared identifier 'scroller' did you mean '_scroller'?`

Comment: I added that into the answer, since I had forgotten to mention where to put it.

Comment: you forgot to add 
`@synthesize scroller;`  add it right under the @implementation in the .m file

Comment: and again, make sure you are connected in IB! you have to add the connection holding down control and dragging a line from the scrollview to the implementation.... I will add a picture if you have problems connecting it.

Comment: bob i think we're almost there - i did link in IB but still see no scrolling - my current structure is like this: `Detail View Controller - Detail/Scroll View/Labels` -- should this be different?

Comment: I updated my answers with pictures, 
try the second picture first since we think it isnt a connection problem with IB, which is making user userInteractionEnabled is checked in the inspector for our scrollview.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17359/discussion-between-torr-and-bob-odenkirk)

Comment: not sure what I was doing, but started from scratch and got it to work - thx!